# How To Insert HTML Tags in TextArea?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i insert HTML Tags in TextArea?

i try this one.

```
string strdetails = Server.HtmlEncode(txtdetails.Text.ToString());
```

and i also add page directive.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mpMember.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="postAlerts.aspx.cs" Inherits="postAlerts" Title="Untitled Page" ValidateRequest="false" EnableViewStateMac="false"%>
```

and also change web.config

```
<system.web>
………………………
<pages validateRequest="false">
</pages>
………………………
</system.web>
```

than also it not work for me. . . any help please..

Comment: The `Server.HtmlEncode` is the solution, you must have an error on implementation if is not working. What is the results ? what is the rendered html ? what did you see, what do you expect ?

Comment: `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client` this error accourted. you say about `Server.HtmlEncode` it work fine at localhost but problem is online.

Comment: This is a totally different question, and that message is only on post back.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: If I remember well you need to add `<pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5">` and this make it work.

Comment: ok that is my mistake sorry about that but any solution on that error ?

Comment: ok i will try `<pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5">` thank you

Comment: Yes this is it, this make it work...